# jquery validation: Show error message for one control alone

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery validate plugin for validating my form. Version: jQuery Validation Plugin v1.15.0. This is how I've tried:

```
$("#myform").validate(
            {
                errorplacement: function(error, element) { },
                rules:
                {
                    customername: "required",
                    mobileno:"required",
                    emailid:{
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    phoneno:"required",
                    projectsponsor:"required",
                    status:"required",
                    loginid:"required",
                    password:"required",
                    confirmpassword:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo: '#password'
                    }
                },
                messages:
                {
                    confirmpassword:{
                        equalTo: 'The two passwords do not match!'
                    }
                }
            });
```

By using this, I've mentioned that all my controls are required. But, I want to show the error message for confirmpassword alone. But, default error message "This Field is required", is displayed for all other controls.

My requirement is, how can I show the error message for confirmpassword control alone, provided all the other fields are required. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the `messages` object, assign the error message to the field name instead of the rule name.  This way the same message will be displayed for all errors on this field.

   ```
   messages: {
       confirmpassword: 'The two passwords do not match!'
   }
   ```
2. It's spelled `errorPlacement`, not `errorplacement`.
3. You should not leave `errorPlacement` empty.  Instead put a `return false` inside and this function is disabled.  However, you do not need `errorPlacement` in order to disable the default messages.  See #4 below.
4. Use [`showErrors`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) instead of `errorPlacement`.  With `showErrors`, you can control each message individually and this function will automatically suppress the default error messages.  The `errorMap` argument contains all field names and error messages as key/value pairs.  Pick out the `confirmpassword` message with `errorMap.confirmpassword`.

   ```
   showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
       var message = (errorMap.confirmpassword) ? errorMap.confirmpassword : '';
       $("#message").html(message);
   },
   ```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/Ljs96zcq/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljs96zcq/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to create group for controls to validate and show error message by group.
You can also use depend on any field as below:

**In depend function you can build your logic when it check for password equal**

```
function isPasswordPresent() {
   return $('#password').val().length > 0;
}

confirmpassword: {
        required: true,            
        equalTo: {
            depends: isPasswordPresent,
            param: "#password"
        }
    },
```